# Can I use a string as conditional compiling Constant

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, outlook, ms-word

Is it possible to use strings constants in conditional compilling in VBA?

for example:

```
#Const This_File_Concept="Chancleta"
'
#If This_File_Concept="Chancleta" then
     ''...Something happens

#End If
'    
#If This_File_Concept="Auto" then
     ''...Something different happens

#End If
'    
#If This_File_Concept="Freesbee" then
     ''...Another thing happens

#End If
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Yes

Demonstration:

```
#Const This_File_Concept = "Chancleta"

#If This_File_Concept = "Chancleta" Then
     Dim zx As Long
#End If
'
#If This_File_Concept = "Auto" Then
     Dim zx As String
#End If
'

Sub Demo_OK()
    #If This_File_Concept = "Chancleta" Then
         zx = 1
    #End If
    '
    #If This_File_Concept = "Auto" Then
        zx = "Hello"
    #End If
End Sub

Sub Demo_Error()
    #If This_File_Concept = "Chancleta" Then
         zx = "Hello"
    #End If
    '
    #If This_File_Concept = "Auto" Then
        zx = 1
    #End If
End Sub
```

Running Sub `Demo_OK` with work fine, no errors.

Running Sub `Demo_Error` with not work, return error 13, `type mismatch`

Comment: HA HA HA HA, I could bite my ears!! :-) I swear I tried my own example before posting and it didnt work. I must have been typing something wrong. Thanks Chris